# C++ runtime symbol lookup error, ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, runtime, undefined-symbol

I have a C++ function doSth that will call a function "checkFrame" from a class "canMsg" as shown below

```
#include "canMsg.h"  
void doSth(char* canFrame){
    map<int, double> returnedData;
    CANMsg canMsg;
    std::cout<<canFrame <<endl;
    canMsg.checkFrame(canFrame);
}
```

During compilation I receive no error, but when I run it, it executes `std::cout<<canFrame <<endl;` statement and crashes by creating an error

```
undefined symbol: _ZNSaIcEC1Ev, version GLIBCXX_3.4
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `$ c++filt <<< "_ZNSaIcEC1Ev"`   `std::allocator<char>::allocator()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. The error was due to my attempt to return a locally declared pointer. After I changed the local pointer variable to a static, it works perfect. The basic idea is C++ does not advocate to return the address of a local variable to outside of the function.

Look [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_return_arrays_from_functions.htm) for more information.

Comment: It should have caused segfault and not a symbol lookup error.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when dependent library(where `_ZNSaIcEC1Ev` id defined) was compiled for other version of GLIBC (newer version or much older), that you currently have.

Try to recompile that library with your current environment.

Also you can add nice switch to `LDFLAGS` of your app: `-Wl,--no-undefined`. Then you can see any undefined symbols at compile time (not sure if it helps in your situation).

Comment: Check my comment, that symbol is straight from the standard library. Don't really want to recompile that yourself.

Comment: I meant, Dangila is uses some shared library where class `CANMsg` is implemented (libCANMsg.so for example). Maybe that library has been compiled with incompatible version of GLIBC.

Answer (score 0):

I think that kind of problem can arise if things are linked in the 'wrong' order. I suggest you try changing the order of whatever libraries you are passing to the linker.

(I don't actually know why the ordering matters - but it sometimes does.)